# On $L^2$ spaces which have an orthogonal basis of characters (complex exponentials)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, approximation-theory, fourier-transform

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. What conditions on $\Omega$ make it so there exists a countable set $\Lambda$ such that $\{e^{2\pi i\lambda t} \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ form an orthogonal basis for $L^2(\Omega) $

Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a countable subset. What conditions on $\Lambda $ make it so that there exists $\Omega $ such that $L^2(\Omega)$ has $\{e^{2\pi i\lambda t} \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ as an orthogonal basis?

I am curious what types of conditions we could look at. The only thing I know people have looked at is with regard to the first problem and revolves around the Fuglede Conjecture which conjectures that $\Omega $ must tiles $\mathbb{R}^n $. Is there anything other kind of geometric or algebraic condition that has been looked at?

Comment: Seems to be related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152438/when-is-a-collection-of-exponentials-dense-in-l2k-k-infty/ and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218182/transform-riesz-basis-ei-lambda-n-t-n-in-mathbb-z-to-an-orthogonal-b/